# Jquery get data from JSON (undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

When i try to get value from json data i getting undefined

```
$.get( baseURL + 'vacation/show/' + name_surname, function( data ) {
    alert(data); // return [{"id":"1","title":"Testas","start":"2015-03-04","end":"2015-03-04"}]
    alert(data.start); // return undefined (should be here 2015-03-04)
});
```

I need get only start value from data, how can i fix this?

Comment: you should parse it using JSON.parse(data)

Comment: replace `$.get` with `$.getJSON`

Comment: Your data is a JSON array! So, you would use `data[0].start` or `data[0]["start"]`

Comment: @DawidC - And no need of `JSON.parse(data)` if there is `dataType: 'json'` when using `$.ajax` method.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is not an object, you need to make an object out of it to be able to access its values. I am not sure what it is at the moment. Hence, I've put a condition to check the type and then alert accordingly.

```
$.get( baseURL + 'vacation/show/' + name_surname, function( data ) {
    alert(data);
    // return [{"id":"1","title":"Testas","start":"2015-03-04","end":"2015-03-04"}]
    if (typeof data === "object") {        
        alert (data[0].start);
    } else {
        alert (JSON.parse(data)[0].start);
    }
});
```

A demo@[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/echfky82/) along the same lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
$.get( url, function( data ) {
    /* do stuff */
}, 'json');
```

or this :

```
$.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
        /* do stuff */
});
```

Comment: Yeah, always... I got used to it... Even if the answer is correct. Probably jealous people or something.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like following:

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
 url: baseURL + 'vacation/show/' + name_surname,
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(data) {
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].start);
  }
 },
 error: function(e) {
  console.log(error);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Before Accessing a Json data from '**data**' object, you need to parse it to Json Object.

you can achieve this as below:

```
var parsedJson=$.parseJSON(data)
```

Here after you can access the json objects like:

```
  alert(parsedJson[i].start);
```

where '**i**' is the index on N-th data set in the Json object, it can take any numeric value ranging from 0,1,..N

Hope this Helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Ty to all, it works fine now, just wondering, or i doing good in my next step, if i retrieve from array for loop and then push only dates into array again to get min date, or it will not be a duplication of work?

```
 $.getJSON( baseURL + 'vacation/show/' + name_surname, function( data ) {
    if(data != '') {
        var dates = [];  
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var date = new Date(data[i].start);
            dates.push(date);
        }

        var minDate = new Date(Math.min.apply(null, dates));
        var year = minDate.getFullYear();
        var month = minDate.getMonth();     

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', year, month);
    }
 });
```